# Loop through nested Json javascript

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, foreach, nested

I'm trying to loop through all the conditions for a form logic system utilizing the json-logic-js library and having issues going into the infinite nested conditions. It works when there is no additional nested operations but can't figure out away to loop through and detect if the condition contains additional conditions infinitely..

What I'm needing is this output

```
{
  "or": [
    {
      "==": [
        "0hxsj03jab9pjsu1",
        "Rig 15"
      ]
    },
    {
      "or": [
        {
          "==": [
            "5l12cnsnxe1911bm",
            "Corporate"
          ]
        },
        {
          "==": [
            "5l12cnsnxe1911bm",
            "Pumping"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "and": [
        {
          "==": [
            "69vsm5bkfb101n2n",
            "Unsafe"
          ]
        },
        {
          "or": [
            {
              "==": [
                "b09ivo9r1aldu6jf",
                "Yes"
              ]
            },
            {
              "==": [
                "0hxsj03jab9pjsu1",
                "Rig 44"
              ]
            },
            {
              "==": [
                "0hxsj03jab9pjsu1",
                "Other"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I currently have this much.

```js
var item = {
      "id":"8wj4xhwe3pd9aage",
      "showif": {
        "operator": "or",
        "conditions": [
            {
                "operator": "and",
                "conditions": [
                    {
                        "data": {
                            "fieldId": "69vsm5bkfb101n2n",
                            "settings": {
                                "values": [
                                    "Unsafe"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "operator": "or",
                        "conditions": [
                            {
                                "data": {
                                    "fieldId": "b09ivo9r1aldu6jf",
                                    "settings": {
                                        "values": [
                                            "Yes"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "data": {
                                    "fieldId": "0hxsj03jab9pjsu1",
                                    "settings": {
                                        "values": [
                                            "Rig 44",
                                            "Other"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "data": {
                    "fieldId": "0hxsj03jab9pjsu1",
                    "settings": {
                        "values": [
                            "Rig 15"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "data": {
                    "fieldId": "5l12cnsnxe1911bm",
                    "settings": {
                        "values": [
                            "Corporate",
                            "Pumping"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    };
    var condition =  [];
    item.showif.conditions.forEach(element => {
      var orC = []
      if(element.data){
        element.data.settings.values.forEach(values => {
          if(element.data.settings.values.length <= 1){
            condition.push({"==": [element.data.fieldId,values]})
           }else{
            orC.push({"==": [element.data.fieldId,values]})
           }
        });   
      
        if(orC.length >= 1){
          condition.push({"or":orC})
        }
      }
      
    
    });

    var Logic = {[item.showif.operator]: condition}
    console.log(Logic)
```

I cant wrap my brain around this without getting lost..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone else with this here is my code :)

```js
var item = {
  "id": "8wj4xhwe3pd9aage",
  "showif": {
    "operator": "or",
    "conditions": [
      {
        "operator": "and",
        "conditions": [
          {
            "data": {
              "fieldId": "69vsm5bkfb101n2n",
              "settings": {
                "values": [
                                    "Unsafe"
                                ]
              }
            }
                    },
          {
            "operator": "or",
            "conditions": [
              {
                "data": {
                  "fieldId": "b09ivo9r1aldu6jf",
                  "settings": {
                    "values": [
                                            "Yes"
                                        ]
                  }
                }
                            },
              {
                "data": {
                  "fieldId": "0hxsj03jab9pjsu1",
                  "settings": {
                    "values": [
                                            "Rig 44",
                                            "Other"
                                        ]
                  }
                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
      {
        "data": {
          "fieldId": "0hxsj03jab9pjsu1",
          "settings": {
            "values": [
                            "Rig 15"
                        ]
          }
        }
            },
      {
        "data": {
          "fieldId": "5l12cnsnxe1911bm",
          "settings": {
            "values": [
                            "Corporate",
                            "Pumping"
                        ]
          }
        }
            }
        ]
  }
};

function loopThrough(obj) {

  var operator = obj.operator
  var condition = [];
  obj.conditions.forEach(element => {
    var orC = []
    if (element.data) {
      element.data.settings.values.forEach(values => {
        if (element.data.settings.values.length <= 1) {
          condition.push({
            "==": [element.data.fieldId, values]
          })
        } else {
          orC.push({
            "==": [element.data.fieldId, values]
          })
        }
      });
      if (orC.length >= 1) {
        condition.push({
          "or": orC
        })
      }
    } else if (element.operator) {
      condition.push(this.loopThrough(element))
    }
  });


  return ({
      [operator]: condition
  })
}


console.log(loopThrough(item.showif));
```